# How to use Combinatorial BLAS?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, blas

I know how to install and use BLAS for C (cblas.h), but I do not know how to use Combinatorial BLAS (CombBLAS).

I am using CentOS 6.5.
Here is what I have installed successfully on my server:

```
# yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
# yum install openmpi openmpi-devel
# yum install atlas atlas-devel
# yum install gnuplot
# yum install lapack lapack-devel
# yum install boost boost-devel
# yum install cmake
```

And this is how I use BLAS in my codes. I create a file helloblas.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cblas.h>

void main()
{
  double result;
  int incx, incy;
  incx = 1;
  incy = 1;
  double x[3] = {1,2,3};
  double y[3] = {3,4,5};
  result = cblas_ddot(3, x, incx, y, incy);
  printf("Result = %lf \n", result);
}
```

Then I compile and execute it successfully using this command:

```
$ gcc helloblas.c -L/usr/lib64/atlas -lcblas
$ ./a.out
```

And then I proceed by installing Combinatorial BLAS ([CombBLAS](http://gauss.cs.ucsb.edu/~aydin/CombBLAS/html/index.html)), using this steps:

```
# wget http://gauss.cs.ucsb.edu/~aydin/CombBLAS_FILES/CombBLAS_beta_14_0.tgz
# wget http://gauss.cs.ucsb.edu/~aydin/CombBLAS_FILES/testdata_combblas1.2.1.tgz
# tar zxvf CombBLAS_beta_14_0.tgz
# cp testdata_combblas1.2.1.tgz CombBLAS
# cd CombBLAS
# tar -xzvf testdata_combblas1.2.1.tgz
# module add openmpi-x86_64
# cmake .
# make
```

The CombBLAS installation was successful since there was no error message.

I have checked the directory of /usr/includes, it contains no library of CombBLAS:
[image: /usr/includes]

The CombBLAS library (CombBLAS.h) is located in the source folder.
[image: /root/CombBLAS]

I have three questions:

1. How to use and include CombBLAS library into your codes? Does anyone have an example source code on how to use CombBLAS? I mean a simple one, just like the helloblas.c above.
2. I install the CombBLAS on my server in order to be used by other users. But since there is no CombBLAS.h in folder /usr/include, then how can they use it? Obviously, normal users are not permitted to access /root directory.
3. Is there any user documentation of CombBLAS?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

One of the authors of CombBLAS has helped me answer my question.
There are several code samples inside folder Applications. For example, we can run it using this command (it run BFS for graph with 2^10 vertices):

```
$ cd Applications/
$ make tdbfs
$ ./tdbfs Force 10
```

There are other executables that can be run: betwcent (Betweenness Centrality), dobfs (Direction Optimization Breadth First Search), fbfs (Filtered Breadth First Search), fmis, and mcl.